# Устарело ли использования i++?

Tags: javascript, инкремент

На одном из англ. язычных вебинаров(не могу вспомнить в каком) услышал, что использования инкримента в формате `i++`, является плохой и устаревшей практикой. Вместо этого советуют использовать `i+=1;`

Вопрос так ли это? Если да, то мне интересна причина и ссылка если есть. Всем спасибо!

P.S. Знаю, что на некоторых языках, таких как `Python` отсутствует `i++`. Возможно не спроста?

P.S.S. Провел синтетический тест и понял, что производительность браузеров семейства Webkit с инкриментом в три раза выше(Разный способ оптимизации движков). В тот момент в FireFox, инкремент проигрывает прилично(обратная сторона). Хоть это сухие тесты, но как я понял, стоит придерживаться классике. Количество пользователей Webkit значительно больше.

Google Chrome:
[image: https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/10643/0/i-i-i1]

Firefox:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Тут можно проверить самим: https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/10643/0/i-i-i1

Comment: Не очень шарю в js, но помойму это бред. Это маловероятно.

Comment: @Victor VosMottor, согласен. Но слышу об этом второй раз. Возможно от фаната Python. Но хотелось бы наверняка знать, чем им вариант i++ не устраивает

Comment: @Node_pro, меня тоже не устраивает отсутствие в питоне инкрементов и декрементов, хотя никто не отменял `i += 1` :D

Comment: @VictorVosMottor, не согласен, но только с `по мойму` =) А вообще, `++i` же лучше.

Comment: В python нет инкремента потому что int — неизменяемый тип. Вы не можете увеличить значение переменной, только назначить тому же имени другой объект равный сумме старого объекта и единицы.

Comment: На самом деле результаты [нормального теста](https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/ShowResult/145872) не столь впечатляющие. Сравнение, присутствующее в любом цикле с инкрементом выравнивает результаты))

Comment: vp_arth, согласен, но только не для Firefox. P.S я думал эти инструменты уже содержать внутри себе цикл)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Видите разницу? А Си-шники видят.

```js
console.log("i++");
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    console.log(i);
}
console.log("i+=1");
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i+=1) {
    console.log(i);
}
console.log("++i");
for (let i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    console.log(i);
}
```

Comment: ну и собственно что там видят сишники?

Comment: а яваскриптники не видят?

Comment: @ДжонниКэтсвилл https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_incdec (инфа про инкремент по С++, наслаждайтесь)

Comment: Сакральный смысл своего примера вы так и не объяснили.

Comment: Между первым и вторым разницу не особо видно) Разве что в Си вообще нет оптимизаций и `i+=1` компилится в `add` вместо `inc`

Comment: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/ae5zTc gcc например полностью идентичный код для трех вариантов дает

Comment: Мне больше нравится вот это: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/3rv95b =)

Comment: @vp_arth в натуре конпелятор умный